# Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0 get Ambiguous reference error to member 'joined'

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I'm working on convert swift 2.3 to swift 3.0;

**Swift 2.3 Code:**

```
extension ContextDidSaveNotification: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    public var debugDescription: String {
        var components = [notification.name]
        components.append(managedObjectContext.description)
        for (name, set) in [("inserted", insertedObjects), ("updated", updatedObjects), ("deleted", deletedObjects)] {
            let all = set.map { $0.objectID.description }.joinWithSeparator(", ")
            components.append("\(name): {\(all)}")
        }
        return components.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.0 Code:**

```
extension ContextDidSaveNotification: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    public var debugDescription: String {
        var components = [notification.name]
        components.append(Notification.Name(rawValue: managedObjectContext.description))
        for (name, set) in [("inserted", insertedObjects), ("updated", updatedObjects), ("deleted", deletedObjects)] {
            let all = set.map { $0.objectID.description }.joined(separator: ", ")
            components.append(Notification.Name(rawValue: "\(name): {\(all)}"))
        }
        return components.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

But I got error: **Ambiguous reference to memeber 'joined()'** for the lase return in Swift 3.0 code.

How to solve this problem? I did a lot research but couldn't found a working solution.

Thanks

Comment: Try explicitly declaring the type on the components var initialization.

Comment: `Notification.Name` is a struct in Swift 3 – rather than a string – which is not what `joined()` expects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`joined(separator:)` is declared for `Array<String>`, not `Array<Notification.Name>`:

```
// somewhere in standard library
extension Array where Element == String {

    public func joined(separator: String = default) -> String
}
```

As @vadian pointed out, `Notification.Name` is not equivalent to `String`, so you need to convert your array first. This should work:

```
components
  .map({ $0.rawValue })
  .joined(separator: " ")
```